# Import eclipse settings to intellijI

Tags: intellij-idea

I've got a stack of eclipse settings for code format. Is there any way to import these into intellij?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't support Eclipse code style settings, however, [there is a plug-in to use external Eclipse code formatting](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=6020) instead of the internal one, so that you will get the same formatting in Eclipse and in IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 6):

With IntelliJ IDEA 13 you can also import eclipse Code formatting settings **without** the need of any plugins.

First you have to export those Code Formatter settings in eclipse. In eclipse go to the `Preferences >> Java >> Code Style >> Formatter and export it via "Export All" option.`

As a result, you will get a XML file.

In IntelliJ, go to `File >> Other Settings >> Default Settings >> Code Style >> Java` >> go to "Manage" >> go to "Import" and select that exported XML file.

Apply Changes and IntelliJ should format automatically now.